# Use redux-framework values in custom made wiget

Tags: php, wordpress, redux-framework

Is it possible to use redux values with echo in a custom made widget?

**`my-widget.php`** is included in **`function.php`** with global **`$opt_name`** defined in top of `fuction.php`

Want to use:

```
echo $opt_name['very-nice-input'];
```

Excerpt from **my-widget.php** showing front-end display of widget.

```
echo $args['before_widget'];
if ( ! empty( $instance['title'] ) ) {
    echo $args['before_title'] . apply_filters( 'widget_title', $instance['title'] ). $args['after_title'];
}
    echo $opt_name['very-nice-input'];
    echo $args['after_widget'];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lead dev of Redux here.

Yes, but you may need to do your own get_option('OPT_NAME') if the values haven't been set yet. Give it a try by declaring your global $OPT_NAME variable. If it's empty, then do a get_option.

:)

Comment: For further reference if someone googles this question: I thought that declaring `global $OPT_NAME;` in function.php would be enough as I included my widget in the bottom of function.php. It showed out that I needed to include `global $OPT_NAME;`  in `my-widget.php` also.

Comment: Addition: Declare `global $OPT_NAME;` inside `public function widget`, or whatever php-function you need the values accessible in.

Comment: There you go. :)   Glad you got it.